# Proving $\cos^5(a)=\cos(a)-2\sin^2(a)\cos(a)$, using only Pythagorean identities

Tags: trigonometry

I came across a problem which said prove using only Pythagorean Identities and I got stumped. Some Insight would be helpful.

$$\cos^5(a)=\cos(a)-2\sin^2(a)\cos(a)$$

What I first did was factor the right side and used the main pythagorean identity to try and simplify but I don't really think it got me anywhere. My final step somehow got me to;

$$\cos^2(a)-\sin^2(a)=\cos^4(a)$$

Where do I go from there or what could I have done differently in the start?

Comment: The relation doesn't hold for, say, $a = 45^\circ$. (The right-hand side vanishes, but the left-hand side does not.)

Comment: the thing you wish to prove is false. Let $a = \pi/4,$ so that $\cos a = \sin a = 1/sqrt 2,$ especially $2 \sin^2 a = 1$

Comment: So, If the book say's prove, It can be unprovable? A bit of a useless problem. Perhaps there is a typo.

Comment: Are you being asked to *prove* that the equation holds for all $a$, or to *solve* it for values of $a$ that work?

Comment: prove for all a.

Comment: @SavvasNicolaou: Since it fails for $a=45^\circ$, this isn't provable. There could be a typographic error in the book. Mistakes happen.

Comment: Alright, Thanks! :)

Comment: If you *were* being asked to solve, then replacing $\sin^2a$ with $1-\cos^2a$ would allow you to rearrange and factor, getting this equation $$\cos a\,\left(1-\cos a\right)^2\left(1+\cos a\right)^2 = 0$$ From this, we can deduce that the relation only holds for integer multiples of $90^\circ$.